# 'EntityState' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Data.EntityState' and 'System.Data.Entity.EntityState'

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm getting the error

> 'EntityState' is an ambiguous reference between
>   'System.Data.EntityState' and 'System.Data.Entity.EntityState'

I'm getting this error on my 4 controllers using **mvc5 entity framework**.

The line in question is `db.Entry(director).State = EntityState.Modified;`

Same on each controller just different models.

Answer (score 1):

Simply provide the fully-qualified EntityState depending on whichone you want:

```
db.Entry(director).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
```

or

```
db.Entry(director).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is two namespace added in your controller named `System.Data` and `System.Data.Entity` and both has `EntityState` property. Compiler is confusing here and gives you the `ambiguous reference` error. You need to specify the property with the namespace like

```
db.Entry(director).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `System.Data.Entity.EntityState` instead of `System.Data.EntityState`.

Comment: Though somewhat related to it, you're not providing an answer to the actual question that is asked.

Answer (score 0):

no need to  provide the fully-qualified.
if there is two using on top of the page:

using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;

**just should delete (using System.Data;)**

**Note: delete another using like (using EntityState = System.Data.EntityState;)**